# HTML Table new row Audible Sound

Tags: php, html, ajax

Good Day

I have a page with a iFrame that uses PHP tables to refresh every 30 seconds drawing new data from SQL database. I am using this table in a control room environment. What I require is that when a new row is added to the iFrame table I need a audible sound / alarm to activate to notify my controllers of a new alarm.

I have read about aJax but never worked with it before is there any other way to notify me when there is a new row?

Comment: You could store a cookie with the row count, if count on incoming page is greater than cookie value ping it. You could also use AJAX to redraw the data rather than the 30 second refreshes.

Comment: How are you currently refreshing the iFrame?

Comment: I am currently using <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="25"> to refresh the Iframe. Normally there is no data in the table as it is moved once actioned. Only new alarms comes to the table